# Transforming a variable that only has values in a fixed range for linear regression

Tags: regression, data-transformation

In developing a linear regression model where some independent variables can only take values in a fixed range (such as FICO scores which go from 300 to 850 or SAT scores which can only go up to 2400), is it ok to use raw values for such variables if other conditions for regression are met? Or is it necessary to transform these variables somehow so that they become “unscaled”? What would be the appropriate transformation in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use linear regression *without regularization term* you will not need to scale the variables.

However, it makes sense [because the results becomes easier to interpret.](https://www.quora.com/Do-I-need-to-do-feature-scaling-for-simple-linear-regression)